# How do I install Ubuntu on a unformatted harddrive?

Tags: format

I would like to install Ubuntu on a computer with an unformatted hard drive, do I need to format my harddrive before installing Ubuntu, or can I just install Ubuntu without any problems?

Greetings,
Bart

Comment: You can just install

Answer (score 1):

@Bart you can install without formatting that HDD. Because Ubuntu is going to do it for you by itself. You have to just click on **Install Ubuntu**, when the Installation window comes in front of you.

Comment: Tankyou very much for your answer!

Comment: There is no need for the `@Bart`, because the question poster _always_ gets a notification about any comment and answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can just boot from the Ubuntu Live-CD and install it.
There will be a menu where you (normally) can select whether you want to install Ubuntu instead of or alongside existing systems. You can also do the partitioning manually (only if you know about Linux partitioning - it is different from Windows).

Be aware that sometimes the existing systems do not all get recognized properly and that if you chose to replace them, ALL partitions might be deleted, data partitions included!
**So back up everything you still might need.**

Comment: I'm amazed about how quik you guys answer, Thanks!

Comment: As you are new here you might not know: When an answer solves your question, you should "accept" it. This shows the community that your problem is solved and will reward the author of the answer a nice reputation bonus (You get some points yourself, too). You do this by clicking on the gray tick on the left of it and it will become green. But only one answer can be accepted, so decide on which one did help you the most.